# Zabbix - for site monitoring zabbix does not check for the next monitor if its found status is ERROR

Tags: zabbix

I've installed zabbix-4.4.5 and trying to set up the URL monitoring. However, for site monitoring, Zabbix does not check for the next monitor if its status is ERROR.

Please find attached image for the reference. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fgbwz.png)

Answer (score 0):

In that case, you are alarmed by a nodata() trigger.

[image: Trigger for nodata in the last 15 minutes]

Comment: the problem statement is: when it found an error in status code, then it's not checking for the rest of the monitor, how I can solve this? I want to monitor all the configurable items.

Comment: the Web Scenario stops at the first error. In order to separately check different URLs without stopping, create separate Web Scenarios.

Comment: ohh.. there are approx 50-60 URLs we need to monitor, in that case, I need to create 50-60 web Scenarios. A really difficult task it is.

Comment: Is there any other way to monitor the URLs flawlessly?